# Ng-bootstrap Typeahead problem with autocomplete?

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, typehead

I have this Angular project based on League of Legends API.

The problem is that I dont know how make the Typeahead work. It should return autocomplete values but throws an error. I'm very confused.
Also, "this.champions" is not an array. If thats the problem, how can I convert it to an array?

**champions.service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ChampionsService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  GetChampions(){
    return this.http.get('http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/10.23.1/data/es_ES/champion.json');
  }

}
```

**HTML**

```
<form [formGroup]="championFindForm" (ngSubmit)="SubmitFind()" novalidate>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <ng-template #rt let-r="result" let-t="pro">
                <ngb-highlight [result]="r.nombre" [term]="t"></ngb-highlight>
            </ng-template>
            <input id="champions" type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="champion" [(ngModel)]="championModel"
                [ngbTypeahead]="search" [inputFormatter]="formatter" [resultFormatter]="formatter" 
                type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre de campeón" aria-label="Nombre de campeón"
                aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Buscar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

**.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {ChampionsService } from '../../services/champions.service';
import { debounceTime, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

type genericModel = {object: string};

@Component({
  selector: 'app-champions',
  templateUrl: './champions.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./champions.component.css']
})

export class ChampionsComponent implements OnInit {

  championFindForm: FormGroup;
  
  public champions;

  public championModel: genericModel;
  formatter = (value: genericModel) => value.object;
  
  constructor(private championsService:ChampionsService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.championFindForm = new FormGroup({
      champion: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    });
    this.GetAllChampions();
  }

  GetAllChampions(){
    this.championsService.GetChampions().subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        this.champions = data.data;
        Object.keys(data.data).map((key: any, obj: any) => obj[key]);
        console.log(this.champions);
      }
    );
  }


  search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
    text$.pipe(
      debounceTime(200),
      map(term => this.champions.filter(v => new RegExp(term, 'mi').test(v.object)).slice(0, 10))
    )

}
```